# Webview stopping unexpectedly issue

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-webview

Im tryign to Create an app that simply launches a web site. I got the code to display no errors but when i run it in the web test things it the app crashes and displays this error message.
"The application webView (process com.webview) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.
Any help would be apreciated.

Below is my code for my class and My Manifest.

```
package com.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity { 

WebView mWebView; 

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
    final Activity mActivity = this; 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    // Adds Progrss bar Support 
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 


    // Makes Progress bar Visible 
    getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON); 

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webview ); 
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);      
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com"); 


    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()  
    { 
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
        { 
            //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading... 
            mActivity .setTitle("Loading..."); 
            mActivity .setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded 

        } 
    }); 
} 
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.webview"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"> 

<WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webview" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
/> 
</LinearLayout> 

</manifest>
```

Debugger shows this below

[2012-02-09 13:57:18 - Emulator] Unknown savevm section type 95

[2012-02-09 13:57:52 - WebView] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'

[2012-02-09 13:57:52 - WebView] Uploading WebView.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

[2012-02-09 13:57:52 - WebView] Installing WebView.apk...

[2012-02-09 13:58:14 - WebView] Success!

[2012-02-09 13:58:14 - WebView] Starting activity com.webview.WebViewActivity on device emulator-5554

[2012-02-09 13:58:15 - WebView] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN

cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.webview/.WebViewActivity }

Comment: Please post the error & stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: Im using Eclypse and new to this all. I have no clue what your asking for or how to find it.

Comment: [2012-02-09 13:57:18 - Emulator] Unknown savevm section type 95

Comment: You should have a DDMS perspective within Eclipse that shows the logcat output in a docked window.  Or `click Window->Show View->Other...`, expand the Android group and choose LogCat from the list.

Comment: ok I found it. But when i ran the app in the enumerator nothing apreared in LogCat

Comment: Look harder. When you get the error dialog you describe, there will be a red stack trace showing the exception that triggered the dialog.

Comment: You put your views in the manifest...? For your particular code sample to work, they should be in a layout file called main.xml because of the call to 'setContentView(R.layout.main)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, what I did was move the declaration of the WebView to the main.xml and with that change works well.

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.webview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

maix.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"> 

    <WebView  
        android:id="@+id/webview" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Ill test this out tommorow morning and get your answer accepted. Apreciate the help.